# Passing multiple data items through checkbox

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have 2 checkbox repeaters: The first gets populated w/ an ArrayCollection & the second gets populated w/ the "Label" and "Data" fields selected from the first checkbox....how do I pass another item to the second checkbox? In the code below, I am currently only passing the "key" and "val" fields & would like to pass "another" field.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <mx:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
            xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
            xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
            creationComplete="updateOlder();"
            >
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import flash.events.MouseEvent;
        import mx.controls.CheckBox;
        import mx.core.Repeater;
        [Bindable]
        public var older:ArrayCollection  = new ArrayCollection ([]);
        [Bindable]
        public var newer:ArrayCollection  = new ArrayCollection ([]);

        private function updateOlder():void{
            older.addItem({key:'item1',val:{ name:'desc1' ,another:'another1'}});
            older.addItem({key:'item2',val:{ name:'desc2' ,another:'another2'}});
            older.addItem({key:'item3',val:{ name:'desc3' ,another:'another3'}});
        }

        private function updateNewer(evt:MouseEvent):void {
            var tmpBox:CheckBox = evt.target as CheckBox;
            if(tmpBox.selected) {
                // add item to array   
                newer.addItem({key:tmpBox.label, val:tmpBox.data.val, another:tmpBox.data.another});
            } 
            else {
                // remove item from array
                var newArrIndex: int = getArrayElementIndex(newer, older[tmpBox.instanceIndex]);
                if(newArrIndex != -1){
                    newer.removeItemAt(newArrIndex);
                }
            }
            newer.refresh();
        }

        private function getArrayElementIndex(arr:ArrayCollection, elementValue:Object):int{
            for (var retInd: int = 0; retInd < arr.length; retInd++) {
                if (arr[retInd]['key'] == elementValue['key'] && arr[retInd]['val']['name'] == elementValue['val']['name']
                    && arr[retInd]['val']['another'] == elementValue['val']['another']) {
                    return retInd;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }       
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<mx:HBox width="100%" height="100%">
    <mx:VBox width="100%" height="100%">
        <mx:Repeater id="oldRepeater" dataProvider="{older}">
            <mx:CheckBox color="black" fontFamily="Arial" fontSize="14"
                         label="{oldRepeater.currentItem.key}" 
                         data="{oldRepeater.currentItem.val}"
                         click="updateNewer(event);"
                         />
        </mx:Repeater>
    </mx:VBox> 
    <mx:VBox width="100%" height="100%">
        <mx:Repeater id="newRepeater" dataProvider="{newer}">
            <mx:CheckBox color="red" fontFamily="Arial" fontSize="14"
                         label="{newRepeater.currentItem.key}"
                         data="{newRepeater.currentItem.val}" 
                         />
        </mx:Repeater>
    </mx:VBox> 
</mx:HBox>
</mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you want to accomplish, but it seems to me the easiest way to go is to make the Object you assign to the "val" field on each of the ArrayCollections contain both variables, i.e.

```
older.addItem({ key:'item1', val:{ name:'desc1' ,another:'another1'} });
```

and retrieve those values later:

```
private function getArrayElementIndex(arr:ArrayCollection, elementValue:Object):int{
            for (var retInd: int = 0; retInd < arr.length; retInd++) {
                if (arr[retInd]['key'] == elementValue['key'] && arr[retInd]['val']['name'] == elementValue['val']['name']
                    && arr[retInd]['val']['another'] == elementValue['val']['another']) {
                    return retInd;
                }
            }
            return -1;
```

Comment: I've updated my code above but get an error on line 1: "Packages cannot be nested"

Comment: That sounds like you have a nested include or package {} declaration somewhere.  Does it go away when you change the code back to your old version?

Comment: yes, it goes away. The problem isn't line 1 but trying to fit multiple items in the "data" field.

Comment: That got rid of the "Packages cannot be nested" error but now I get "TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties" w/in the getArrayElementIndex function. I've updated my code above to your suggestion

Comment: You need to change the call to addItem for the other ArrayCollection as well.  "newer" still has the old val and another fields.

Comment: yes, that worked. 1 last question, how do I now bind the "another" field to the "label" of my second checkbox? label="{newRepeater.currentItem.val}"

Comment: label="{newRepeater.currentItem.val.another}" - it's a regular field.

Comment: you are correct...it does work but I get a warning that "databinding will not be able to detect assignments to 'val'".....it works though & at this point that's all I care about. thx!